# Swap Ether to tokens on Uniswap V2 Router Gas Estimation Error

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, uniswap

I am trying to buy DAI tokens from my smart contract using `IUniswapV2Router02`:

```solidity
contract BuyToken {
  address internal constant UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS = 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D; //  Uniswap Router Address
  address private multiDaiKovan = 0x4F96Fe3b7A6Cf9725f59d353F723c1bDb64CA6Aa; // DAI Kovan Address, Mainet: 0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F
  IUniswapV2Router02 public uniswapRouter;

  constructor() {
    uniswapRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS);
  }

  function getPathForETHtoToken() private view returns (address[] memory) {
    address[] memory path = new address[](2);
    path[0] = uniswapRouter.WETH();
    path[1] = multiDaiKovan;

    return path;
  }

  function getEstimatedETHforToken(uint daiAmount) public view returns (uint[] memory) {
    return uniswapRouter.getAmountsIn(daiAmount, getPathForETHtoToken());
  }

  event Debug(
    uint256 ethAmountDerivable
  );

  function buy(uint tokenAmount) public payable {
    uint deadline = block.timestamp + 15; 
    uint ethAmountDerivable = getEstimatedETHforToken(tokenAmount)[0];

    // Swap ETH for DAI
    uniswapRouter.swapETHForExactTokens{ value: ethAmountDerivable }(daiAmount, getPathForETHtoToken(), address(this), deadline);

    IERC20 token = IERC20(multiDaiKovan);
    require(token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), tokenAmount), 'transferFrom failed.');
    require(token.approve(address(uniswapRouter), tokenAmount), 'approve failed.');

    emit Debug(ethAmountDerivable);
  }

  // important to receive ETH
  receive() payable external {}
}
```

If I try on Remix to call the `getAmountsIn` and paste the value for `swapETHForExactTokens` it works fine, but directly using the variable to supply into the swap function causes `Gas Estimation Error`. I looked into the value of `ethAmountDerivable` the result is just exactly the same as the one I am pasting.

Why do I get gas estimation error even if the value I used manually and thru variable is exactly the same? And how do I resolve this?